# Use a selection of text as a variable in a listbox using C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the title from a selection of code which uses a similar format to XML but all I get in the listbox is "string [] array"

The code I'm targeting is:

```xml
<Pair key="title"><String> bioshock</String></Pair>
```

Trying to isolate and display the "bioshock" section in a listbox, this is what my code looks like:

```cs
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"./path/test12321/USRDIR/podcast.xml");

for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
{
    int start = fileLines[i].IndexOf("> ");
    int end = fileLines[i].LastIndexOf("<");
    fileLines[i] = fileLines[i].Substring(1+start) + fileLines[i].Substring(end+1);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"./tempdata/");
    File.WriteAllLines(@"./tempdata/title.title", fileLines);
}

{ }

{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Add(fileLines);
}
```

Comment: When the system doesn't know what the proper result of a call to `.ToString()` should be it returns the Type of the object.

Comment: You should try `String.join()` method, to concat the elements of that array.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  I think in this case you would be better off using classes from the .NET Framework that are designed specifically to read XML. Specifically, the XmlDocument class and Xpath expressions.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256471%28v%3Dvs.100%29) for more information on XPath syntax.  It is basically a query language for XML.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"./path/test12321/USRDIR/podcast.xml");

// Select all the titles using XPath
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//Pair/String");

foreach(XmlNode node in list)
{
   // Get the contents of each <String> tag
   listBox1.Items.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the elements of your array is the information that you want to display in the `<String>` element, then you can concatenate them with `String.Join()` like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Join(", ", fileLines));
```

This should display all your `fileLines` separated with a coma.

For more information about the `String.Join` method you can refer [here, to Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: FYI, you should consider to use .NET classes as in Mike Marshall's answer